# Why are some many OpenCL examples written in C++ and not in C?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

*Disclaimer: the author is at the beginner level in C/C++.*

Wikipedia says that "OpenCL includes a language (based on C99) for writing kernels".

But if you look at any example of code in the OpenCL Programming Guide book, you will see that alongside with the kernel .cl file there is always a .cpp file (or even few of them).

("Although many of the example applications described throughout this
book have been developed using the programming language C++, we have
focused exclusively on the OpenCL C API for controlling the OpenCL
component.")

Does that mean that the kernels are written in C-like language, while all the other stuff (like memory objects management) is written in C++? Why everything is not written in the C-like language? Doesn't the C++ binding introduce an overhead?

Comment: Why? Because they can, obviously. And there is no overhead in calling a C API from C++. Even an overhead of P/Invoking that C API from .NET is marginal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does that mean that the kernels are written in C-like language, while all the other stuff (like memory objects management) is written in C++?

OpenCL itself is an extension of C99, so the `.cl` files are written in that. You'd have to check what's in the C++ files to see what's implemented in them.

> Why everything is not written in the C-like language?

The authors probably find C++ more convenient.

> Doesn't the C++ binding introduce an overhead?

No, because the C/C++ bridge defined in the C++ language standard can be implemented with virtually zero overhead. It might depend a bit on the compiler, but usually, when you call a C function from C++, it's as cheap as calling the function from C. C++ itself follows C's "zero overhead" philosophy: its advanced (compared to C) features aren't free, but you don't pay for what you don't use.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ binding may introduce a small overhead, but it's on the CPU side. Remember that these examples serve as tutorials. There's nothing to stop you writing your code in C. I'd guess that it's easier to write example applications in C++ because the use of a higher level language allows the reader to see the important details more easily and not be drowned in the morass of low-level memory management that blights C code.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean that the kernels are written in C-like language, while all the other stuff (like memory objects management) is written in C++?

OpenCL has two parts:

- A language for writing kernels. Kernels run on the GPU or equivilent.
- An API which allows a program running on the normal CPU to ask the system to run kernels.

The program which uses OpenCL API can be written in any language that can call a C API. Could be C, C++, Java, Python, Ruby, or anything else that can do a function call to a C library.

> Why everything is not written in the C-like language?

...because that language has been specifically designed for writing the kernel. You can't write a general purpose program in it.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is called from a host code. The kernel is written in OpenCL while the host code may be written in any other language provided that the bindings for calling OpenCL from the host code exist. C++ is a popular choice for the host code but I have seen references to other languages such as C# and FORTRAN.